# issues to split the string in flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex

hi am trying to split the string in flex,but i can't to separate correctly

```
private var image_path:String = "http://pvm4.yyy.in/sample-31/demo/img0.jpg";
```

I want to split the number `0`

so am trying this code

```
image_path.substring(image_path.lastIndexOf("/img"));
```

but am getting img0.jpg i need `0` only how to split this?

Comment: Why don't you use the split method directly ?

Comment: the url is before /img is dynamically added . img0,img1,img2....... only same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
image_path.substring(image_path.lastIndexOf("/img")+4, image_path.length-4);
```

Comment: note that the +4 is because /img has length 4, and the -4 is because .jpg also has length 4

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way but by adding the length of your parameter :

(the syntax could not be good as I don't know flex)

```
image_path.substring(image_path.lastIndexOf("/img") + "/img".length);
```

But you sould use the following regex to get the number :

```
.*/demo/img([0-9]+)\.jpg
```

then use capturing group to get the number ;)

Comment: I updated the code with a regex. Regex is a better way to get this kind of pattern